# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed

Tags: c++, macos, shared-libraries

What is this error related to? Is this a lib mismatch?

Happens when I try to run a binary I compiled. I can provide more details if needed.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _COMP_zlib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/Work/projects/water_db_writer/libs/mysql/lib64/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _COMP_zlib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/Work/projects/water_db_writer/libs/mysql/lib64/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(water_db_writer)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/mysql/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/mysql/lib64)

include_directories(/opt/local/include/)
link_directories(/opt/local/lib/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(water_db_writer main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(water_db_writer mysqlcppconn8 ssl crypto)
```

Comment: Did you actually link in zlib? If so, how?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I did not explicitly link zlib. Updated question with CMake config.

Comment: Try adding `zlib` to your `target_link_libraries` - I think `ssl` relies on having that (unless it's compiled with `no-comp` - but it probably isn't in this case). By no means certain....